# How to get the second line of a string in Python

Tags: python, string

I'm using a web service which responds like this....

```
error code|text|reference
0|sms submitted|11010d3b0d6872af47b938aebb450d06-3
```

At the moment I check if `status_msg starts` with `error`

```
 if status_msg.startswith('error'):
```

which is a bad way of doing it.

How Can I get the actual `error code` from the response in Python in this example it is `0`

I have tried this `go to second line, get first number`:

```
 if status_msg.startswith('error') and not status_msg.splitlines()[2][1:] == 0:
```

Comment: Your index of `2` is the third line actually, since indexes start at `0`.

Comment: The other problem is with `[1:]`, that is everything from the second characters onwards. You want `[:1]`, which is everything _up to_ the second character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert it to a dictionary:

```
>>> s = '''error code|text|reference
0|sms submitted|11010d3b0d6872af47b938aebb450d06-3'''
>>> d = dict(zip(*(line.split('|') for line in s.splitlines())))
>>> d
{'text': 'sms submitted',
 'reference': '11010d3b0d6872af47b938aebb450d06-3',
 'error code': '0'}
```

Comment: this works too ``response = dict(zip(*(line.split('|') for line in res.text.splitlines()))`` thanks

Comment: Both answers given work for me. I decided to pick this answer as ``accepted`` as it seem to be more robust. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Close...try this:

```
(msg, reference) = status_msg.splitlines()[1][1:]
#                                          ^ This index should be 1, not 2.
```

Indices into iterables in Python are zero-based, not one-based.  The result of that expression should be a two-element list containing the "sms" message and the code.